# Which Linux distribution for PHP web site coding

Tags: php, linux

I am coding a website in php. I want to setup a Linux distribution. So, which one i should setup to the my computer?

In the future, i want to learn C++ and Python. 
I think [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com) is a usable distribution. but i can't decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next to every Linux distribution includes C++, Python, and php compilers/interpreters, tools, and editors. For a beginner, Ubuntu is a good start.